# Battlestar Galactica: meaning of a Quorum card that destroys ships

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I have a question regarding a specific Quorum card in Battlestar Galactica.  I don't remember its title, but it has in its text something like "Destroy 3 raiders, a heavy raider, or a centurion token".  The question is, how should this text be parsed?

1) Choose one of three: destroy 3 raiders, OR destroy 1 heavy raider, OR destroy 1 centurion

or

2) Choose one of two: destroy 3 raiders and one heavy raider, OR destroy 1 centurion?

Our playgroup ruled the variant (2) in the game we've played, but we still have our doubts, hence this question.  Ideally, the answer would have a link to an official source, but a good logical argument will also suffice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The card is *Authorization of Brutal Force*. The exact text is:

> Destroy 3 raiders, 1 heavy raider, or 1 centurion.

The person playing the card can choose one of the three options.

I don't think you'll find any official rule that will answer the question. It really comes down to standard English grammar. Option #1 is the proper way to parse that sentence. If option #2 is what was intended, it would have to be written the way you wrote it, i.e. with the "and".